# My program outputs wrong value and unknown error

Tags: c

It's problem that I'm trying to solve for my begginer programming class. I need to enter change and calculate how many coins I neeed to give back.

this is my code:

```
int main(void)
{    
//prompts user for amount of change and check the value of the imput
int n = get_float("enter change owned: ");

//converts to p.
int change = n * 100; 

if ( change > 0)
{
printf("total change is: %ip\n" , change ); 
} 
else
{
    printf(" ERROR: change given needs to be positive value!\n");
}
while(n < 0); 
int i = 0;

//calculate quarters
while (change >= 250) 
{
n = change - 250;
  i++;     
}

//calculate dimes
while (change >= 100) 
{
 n = change - 100;
  i++;     
}
//calculate nickels
while (change >= 50) 
{
 n = change - 50;
  i++;     
}
//calculate pennies
while (change >= 1) 
{
 n = change - 1;
  i++;     
}
 printf("%d\n", i);    
 }
```

I don't understaind why when I enter n = 2.50 and program needs to calculate change as n = n *100 it outputs result as 200 :S. also my program compiles but then when I run it I get following msg: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2147483647 + 1 cannot be represented in type 'int'

thank you!

Comment: You do not update the change variable, so your loop are infinite.

Answer (score 2):

```
int n = get_float("enter change owned: ");
```

it casts float as integer, so 2.4 becomes 2.
Change to :

```
float n = get_float("enter change owned: ");
```

also you might want to check this line :

```
printf("total change is: %ip\n" , change );
```

to print out integer i would recommend :

```
printf("total change is: %d\n" , change );
```